# Android Studio 3.0.1 failed to add android-library dependency to java-library module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have following project structure:

[image: ProjectStructure]

I want to add a data module dependency (data module is android-lib) into domain module (domain module is java-lib). When I've done this I got this messages:

[image: gradle error message]:

Here is my domain\build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  implementation project(':data')
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

And data\build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }

    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
           'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }

   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }

   testOptions {
       unitTests {
           includeAndroidResources = true
       }
   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//<!-- RxJava
   implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
   implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
   core:3.0.1'
   testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.5.1'
   //<!-- OrmLite
   implementation  'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.0'
   implementation  'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'
   //<!-- XStream
   implementation ('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.10') {
      exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
   }
   //<!----SLF4J
   implementation  'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'

   //<!-- RetroFit
   implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
   implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
   implementation  'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'

   }
```

And finally - whole project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       google()
       maven {
           url "https://maven.google.com"
       }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files


    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I can't understand what is really wrong here and why my project doesn't build.

UPD settings.gradle

```
include ':presentation', ':data', ':domain'
```

Comment: post your settings.gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti please see updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `presentation` depend on `domain`? If so you either need to make `data` also a dependency of `presentation`, or use `api project(':data')` in the `domain` build.gradle instead of `implementation project(':data')`.

This is because `implementation` doesn't leak its dependencies up to modules that depend on it, whereas `api` does. So in your config `presentation` can't see `data`. See more info on the official docs here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations